# Remove last letter of each word Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have list of 10000 words and I want to remove the "s" from end of each word.

- Clocks
- Bracket Clocks
- Wall Clocks
- Wardrobes

[image]

Does anyone know a formula to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the last character of the string if it's an "s" and leave it as-is otherwise:

```
=IF(RIGHT(C1,1)="s",LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-1),C1)
```

Where your words are in column C.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you veyr much

Answer (score -1):

Excel function, assuming data is in column C:

```
=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-1)
```

Comment: That would take off the last letter regardless of if it's an s or not, e.g. turn "Furniture" into "Furnitur"